# What "tools" are available within pure mathematics to visualize more advanced topics?

Tags: analysis, soft-question, visualization

What "tools" exist within mathematics to visualize concepts for more advanced areas of mathematics, particularly within Analysis, Topology <s>and Algebra</s> ? Furthermore, can one rigorously integrate such "visual tools" within proofs?

As an example here are some that I've encountered so far:,

- I've seen commutative diagrams for compositions of maps.
- Another example is the following: If $X, W \subset \mathbf{R}^2$ are subsets of the plane, we can draw a picture of a map $f : X \to W$ by colouring $X$ with some pattern, and then colouring each point $(u,v)= f(x,y)$ by the same colour as $(x,y)$ as shown in the free book [Stokes’s Theorem (Benjamin McKay)](https://euclid.ucc.ie/mckay/analysis/analysis.pdf) (on pages 3-4).

Edit: By visualization, I mean anything that conveys information diagrammatically or without the use of words, which hold true for the examples I provided.

Comment: This is not a good question, it's far too broad in several possible dimensions - there are many "advanced topics", different people have different conceptions of what a "visualization" is, and what it means to rigorously integrate a visualization into a proof is subjective.

Comment: I specified which areas I am most interested in: Analysis and Topology, and gave examples of what I mean by visualization. I have edited the question to include an explanation of "visualization".

Comment: It seems like your two examples belong to very different categories.  The second is a way of illustrating a particular mapping - if you are interested in those, this is going to be a very long list.  The first is at a much higher level of abstraction.

Comment: I'd be interested to see more examples of rigorous use of visualizations within higher mathematics.  If you're interested in the second type, you might take a look at Tristan Needham's "Visual Complex Analysis" which has a plethora of very enlightening illustrations.